# Bull Queue Concurrency Control in PM2

Tags: javascript

```js
const bullQueue = require('bull');
const queue = new bullQueue('taskqueue', {...})
const concurrency = 5;
queue.process('jobTypeA', concurrency, job => {...do something...});
```

1 node instance, this code works fine.

But I start 8 instances with PM2 and actually the concurrency will become 40.

How can I control concurrency under multiple instances of PM2?

Comment: In fact, I am using the nestjs framework, the above code is just for easy explanation